# What /me/interests returns from Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

What is supposed to be returned when Facebook Graph API end edge is `interests`?Currently it is returning balnk in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This return `The interests listed on someone's profile under Likes > Interests.`

For more details on this please refer [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/interests)